# How to Convert keyPressed() to touch hold for mobile in p5.js

Tags: p5.js

I just made a game using p5.js. In that game I just need to press and hold spacebar for movement. And now I want to make it for mobile version but I don't know how to convert press and hold space bar to touch and hold for mobile. So does anyone know how to convert them?

Comment: Do you want to use a joystick type movement?

Comment: no i just want to convert press and hold spacebar controll to press and hold the screen. so i just want to make the screen just like the keyboard, so there's only one controll press and hold the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`mouseIsPressed`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseIsPressed) boolean.

```js
function draw() { 
    ...
    if (mouseIsPressed) {
        movement(); // or add whatever you are using for movement here
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: @DevenValisten Thanks, can you please accept it then?